# how to let a discordbot execute a command without using a command in discord but live data?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The thing i want to do is executing a module command by a trigger, like when it receive data it does execute the !servertest.

Right now i only can execute it trough discord with this command !servertest.

What i want to achieve is that if the bot gets information from my code that checks every now and then if a number is received trough telnet (socket.on) it should trigger my module !servertest

Right now my socket.on script receives a number and sends it into discord, but i want it to let it trigger also an !command to automate.

Or how can a bot execute a command by itself without using !servertest in discord?

Ofcourse !servertest executes normally in discord.

i did try this but nothing happens

```
client.commands.get('servertest').run();
```

the command !servertest is on a other js config, server.js containing :

```
module.exports.help = {
        name: "servertest"
}
  
  
  
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {MY CODE}
```

Comment: Instead of checking if the message content is `equal to` "servertest", just check if the message content `includes` "servertest" or which ever you want to check using the `String.prototype.includes()` function.

Comment: ok, but how can i let it execute the !servertest command, its on a different name.json using  module.exports.help = {name: "servertest"}

Comment: @Radnerus  i did update the question.